# dnu restore fails on mac

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I download visual studio code for mac today. I tried to create a simple asp.net 5 web application following these instructions https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5

When I open my web application folder in visual studio, it says I need to run a restore command.

I ran the `dnu restore` command just like the instructions tell me but it seems to always fail.

I receive different errors every time I run it. But most of them are like this one:

> CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Threading/4.0.10-beta-22816
>   SharpCompress.Common.ArchiveException: Could not find Zip file Directory at the end of the file.  File may be corrupted.
>   Restore failed

There is a stack trace as well, but for brevity sake I'll omit it for now

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I ran dnu restore again today. Now I am getting this error 

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dnu restore --no-cache`.

You may also need to remove previously downloaded files - check `~/.dnx/packages`.  I removed all files from that folder some time before trying the above.  Also, see the comments below, if `~/.dnx/runtimes` contains unexpected versions removing them may also work.  Note that the current runtime version can be controlled using `dnvm`.

I never saw the NullReference exception, but I was getting the SharpCompress.Common.ArchiveException.  I suspect there was a mismatch from what dnu thought was the cache state with the actual cache state (maybe something timed out the first time or something).

Comment: I tried that command and I no longer get the null reference excpetion but I still get 

Could not find Zip file Directory at the end of the file. File may be corrupted. Restore failed.

Comment: Sometime last night I did manually remove everything from ~/.dnx/packages, maybe try that first.  If it helps I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I navigated to ~/.dnx and I did not have a packages folder. But I did notice that under runtimes I had two dnx-mono runtimes. dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta4 and dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta5-11674. I removed dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta5-11674 and ran the `dnu restore --no-cache` and it worked. After running it this time I ended up with a packages folder under ~/.dnx. Thanks to your suggestion I was able to figure this out. Update your answer and I'll accept it